# How does switching between two frequencies take place in a dual band MIMO WLAN system?

Tags: wireless-networking, dual-band

Since WLAN can operate on both 2.4 and 5 GHz, I would like to know how the switching between frequencies takes place in these systems. How will the system decide and switch by itself in which frequency it should transmit out of the two.

Comment: Are you referring to clients or access points?

Comment: Are you talking about systems that operate on both bands simultaneously or systems that only operate on one band at a time?

Comment: I want to know about access point operation....also how the client operation is different from AP operation.

Comment: This is about dual band system which operates only one band at a time.

Comment: how will the client determine how to use either of the two frequencies?

Answer (score 1):

On the AP side, there are two kinds of dual-band APs:

1. Ones that only have one radio, and thus only support one band at a time. Examples include the first 802.11n Apple AirPort Extremes from 2007, as well as the first Apple AirPort Time Capsule (2008), and the first 802.11n edition of the Apple AirPort Express (2008).
2. Ones that have two radios that can operate simultaneously. These are called "simultaneous dual-band", or "dual-band concurrent" APs. Examples include all Apple AirPort Extreme, Express, and Time Capsule models introduced in 2009 or later.

For the one-band-at-a-time models, the owner/admin had to pick which band he wanted the AP to operate in. They didn't auto-switch between bands.

For the simultaneous dual-band models, the support both bands simultaneously using separate radios, so they never have to switch. They serve both bands continuously at all times.

The band and channel to be used for a given AP's 802.11 network cell (BSS) is determined by the AP. Clients have to use the band and channel of the AP they are trying to join. If more than one AP in range of the client is publishing the same network name (SSID), then the client can choose which AP it wants to try to join. The IEEE 802.11 standard does not dictate the client's AP selection algorithm; it leaves it up to the implementors as an implementation detail. Many implementations of dual-band client devices will scan both bands and pick whichever AP has the highest signal strength, regardless of band.

After a client is associate to one AP, it may roam (handoff) to another AP publishing the same SSID. Just like the initial AP selection algorithm, the IEEE 802.11 standard does not dictate a roaming algorithm, but leaves it as an implementation detail. Many client implementations define a "roaming threshold" which is a signal strength (RSSI) below which they decide the should start scanning and looking for opportunities to roam. A typical roam threshold might be -70dBm RSSI. There is usually also a second threshold (again, an RSSI) that potential roam candidates must be above in order for the client to roam. This keeps clients from thrashing/flapping back and forth between two equally low RSSI APs. A typical value for this threshold is that the new AP's RSSI must be at least 10dB higher than the old AP.

If a client drops below its roam threshold and scans and sees that its best choice is a different AP that happens to be on a different channel or band, and that new AP's RSSI is enough better than the old AP's RSSI, it will join that new AP and use the band/channel the new AP is using.

Answer (score 0):

Some systems operate on just one of the two bands, so they never switch. On those that do switch, it's often the AP which supports both. The client PC's pick one of the two, and the AP talks back using the same band as the client.

I believe channel bonding cannot yet unify 2.4 and 5 Ghz bands, but this is in the works. You might even get pre-standard hardware from some vendors (i.e. it works if all of your HW is from one vendor.)